# Double display of formulas

Tags: bug, mathjax

Lately I've been experiencing some problems with the the display of formulas. Occasionally I get something like in this picture.[image]

I'm using Chrome on Windows 7. So far I couldn't find anything that is responsible for this neither could I produce this display on purpose. Does anyone know what might cause this/how to fix this/if it affects only me?

Comment: Usually, MathJax rendering bugs can be "fixed" by refreshing the page (perhaps more than once) before they are fixed in code.

Comment: The same problem has been reported [earlier](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20867/11619). I have experienced this problem, too. I'm using Firefox on Windows 7. Usually exiting and reloading helps. Just refreshing the page does not always work (even if yoou do it multiple times).

Comment: @Jyrki: Are you trying hard refresh? (Ctrl+F5)

Comment: Probably not. Thanks for the tip, @Asaf.

Comment: Ok, so it's not a new problem. I'll try the hard refresh as well next time it happens!

Comment: @Jyrki, Hirshy: I'm not saying it will solve the problem; but if refreshing helps at all, then hard refresh is probably the answer.

Comment: Hard refresh works fine for me :). As a side note, hard refresh on apple is done with ``cmd+shift+R``

Comment: This problem only started for me after [rendering MathJax in chat](http://tinyurl.com/cfqcvpc).